# iphone: parsing a string

Tags: iphone, parsing

Hey I have a response string in this format

ok my original resonse string is like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
     "name": "Santa Fe Plaza",
     "category": "Landmark",
     "location": {
        "city": "Santa Fe",
        "state": "NM",
        "country": "United States",
        "latitude": 35.687071155202,
        "longitude": -105.93767717603
     },
     "id": "108196762542063"
  },
  {
     "name": "Museum of Contemporary Native Arts",
     "category": "Museum/art gallery",
     "location": {
        "street": "108 Cathedral Place",
        "city": "Santa Fe",
        "state": "NM",
        "country": "United States",
        "zip": "87501",
        "latitude": 35.686915835451,
        "longitude": -105.93725120129
     },
     "id": "106209180361"
  }
```

]
}

I have to extract all  the names from there Please enlighten me how to achieve this
JSON parser is throwing error all the time

Thanx in advance

Comment: nope this is a response string can you suggest me how to parse this

Comment: most probably it's JSON as Jhaliya remarked.

Comment: yupp this string I get after one round of JSON parsing but I want it to get further split down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by downloading the [JSON framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)

And a Good Tutorial to Start learning: [JSON Framework for iPhone](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/json-framework-for-iphone-part-2.html)

Also see: [How to parse JSON files on iPhone in Objective-C into NSArray and NSDictionary](http://www.xprogress.com/post-44-how-to-parse-json-files-on-iphone-in-objective-c-into-nsarray-and-nsdictionary/)